# Protractor integration with AngularJS in terms of timing when no requests to server is made

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I need to make sure that when testing an AngularJS app with Protractor I don't need to add explicit sleeps between steps.

I was able to find in Protractor's/Angular's code that Protractor is aware of requests made through the $http service and waits for their completion before continuing with a next step: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/3bad3fa440a4a51f57d08c222e7b7fd4fb7781ce/lib/clientsidescripts.js#L28

But I wasn't able to find how it takes the digest cycle into account to wait for that to complete before proceeding.

Probably it's not needed as client side operations don't take long and Selenium itself has a mechanism that waits for an element to appear before continuing, but I need to be sure this is reliable.

Answer (score 1):

I never faced any synchronization issue yet between protractor and my apps `$digest` cycles.

I think the Protractor internal `waitForAngular` is doing its job. I found this for more info:

> Protractor attempts to synchronize with your page before performing actions. **This means waiting for all $timeout or $http requests to resolve, as well as letting the current $digest cycle finish.** If your page has not synchronized within the script execution timeout, Protractor will fail with the message 'Timed out waiting for Protractor to synchronize with the page'.

**from [Debugging Protractor Tests - docs](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/92935f7c275c6513ff83f8f94560d5f0a0c032dc/docs/debugging.md)**.

You should also see the note about [Control Flow](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/control-flow.md).